# How to call animation event from another GameObject

Tags: unity

I have an animation event but I want it to call a function from a script that is attached to a different GameObject that I'm not animating. Is this even possible?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried somehow storing the reference of the script but that required me to create a script to store an additional field to my animated object just to call that specific function. All I want to do is to be able to call a static manager's function. Is there a way to store a reference without creating a specific script?

Answer (score 2):

> You can increase the usefulness of Animation clips
>    by using Animation Events, which allow you to call functions in the object’s script at specified points in the timeline.
>   https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html

So you can call functions only in the object's scripts.

You can make a manager which has functions to call functions from other objects, and you can use that manager on all your animation events in your entire project. just so that you won't need to make a bunch of scripts for each of your animation events.

Comment: Yea...I was trying to avoid this solution because It would lead to various other groups of animated gameobjects having their own managers. I was trying to make use of unity's inspector to do the job. I guess I just have to implement them in code now. Thanks anyway :))

Comment: @StrengthPlusPlus you're welcome. I personally create a manager to manage all the function redirections and then add it as a component to every game object which needs to redirect to another function, which includes animation event redirections.

Answer (score -1):

1. Use a **singleton** instance of the first script. Write `Method1` there.
2. Call `Method1` using singleton instance in a `Method2` in the script attached to the animating GO.
3. Use `Method2` in animation event.

Don't see any other way. At least this avoids dragging the script object reference.

Comment: you need more explanation that really what is you goal